# bash: cd: catkin_ws/src/: No such file or directory

Tags: ros

Whenever I try to start create package by opening new terminal and running cd catkin_ws/src/  this command I am getting error line mentioned below. What should I do?

bash: cd: catkin_ws/src/: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually create the directories. `mkdir catkin_ws/src`